# Deploying Bitbucket to Azure Web Site: add private nuget package server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, nuget, bitbucket

I have set up a website on Azure to deploy through a Bitbucket repository. The process fails when it tries to install nuget packages which are stored on a private nuget server, not nuget.org. Is there a way to specify where to restore the nuget packages from so that Azure can restore these packages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a [custom NuGet.config](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) file at the same level as your .SLN file.

You can then make the following modifications (assuming that your private feed requires authentication, create a set of credentials which only are used for this site):

```
<activePackageSource>
  <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
</activePackageSource>
<packageSources>
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  <add key="custom_package_source" value="https://custom_package_source/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/" />
</packageSources>
<disabledPackageSources />
<packageSourceCredentials>
  <custom_package_source>
    <add key="Username" value="CustomUsername" />
    <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="CustomPassword" />
  </custom_package_source>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

When you deploy via Kudu, this should allow the build process to discover your private feed, authenticate & restore your packages.

If you do not require authentication against your private feed, remove the `<packageSourceCredentials>` element.

Comment: I have this custom file, have  for a while. Works great on my dev pc, but when I deploy to azure via git (webhook to gitlab) it doesn't seem to use my custom repos. Just ignores them entirely. How can I fix this?

Comment: This only works if your private repo is accessible from Azure.