# Azure build - [error]Unable to find version '' of package

Tags: azure, syncfusion

Im trying to get a solution with Syncfusion to work.

But every time I try to deploy to Azure i get the following errors

```
##[error]Unable to find version '13.3.0.12' of package 'Syncfusion.AspNet.Mvc5'.
##[error]Unable to find version '13.3.0.12' of package 'Syncfusion.JavaScript'.
##[error]Unable to find version '13.3.0.12' of package 'Syncfusion.Web.Base45'.
##[error]Unable to find version '13.3.0.12' of package 'Syncfusion.Web.FileFormatsBase45'.
##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
```

I tried creating a NuGet.config with the link to the syncfusion but dont work.

If i check the Packages folder i can see all the packages it says it cant find

Hope somone can help

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using private NuGet feed, as these packages are not listed on the official NuGet feed, thus the error message.
Here is confirmation that these packages are not listed on the public NuGet feed:

http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Syncfusion.AspNet.Mvc5
http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Syncfusion.JavaScript
http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Syncfusion.Web.Base45
http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Syncfusion.Web.FileFormatsBase45

Which is also confirmed by the Syncfusion docs, which describe a custom feed for their packages: http://help.syncfusion.com/extension/syncfusion-nuget-packages/nuget-install-and-configuration

To enable restore of Syncfusion packages, check [this SO question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884875/deploying-bitbucket-to-azure-web-site-add-private-nuget-package-server) on how can you include custom NuGet feeds to your Azure Web app deployment.